# Getting the data from the Custom View Renderer in the platform specific from Shared Project in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-view

I am developing a mobile application using Xamarin.Forms. In my application, I am implementing custom camera using a custom view. I have successfully implemented the custom camera view. What I am trying to do now is, I would like to retrieve some data from custom view renderer in the platform-specific when a button is clicked which is inside the shared project. See my scenario below.

This is my CameraPage.xaml in the shared project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MementoApp.Views;"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="Capture your moment"
             Padding="0,20,0,0"
             x:Class="MementoApp.Views.CameraPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

            <local:CameraPreview x:Name="Camera" Camera="Rear" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Button x:Name="buttonCapturePhoto" Text="Capture photo" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

As you can see, the CameraPreview is the custom view. I also added a button below it.

this is the CameraPreview class

```
namespace MementoApp.Views
{
    public enum CameraOptions
    {
        Rear,
        Front
    }

    public class CameraPreview : View
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CameraProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "Camera",
            returnType: typeof(CameraOptions),
            declaringType: typeof(CameraPreview),
            defaultValue: CameraOptions.Rear);

        public CameraOptions Camera
        {
            get { return (CameraOptions)GetValue(CameraProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CameraProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

In the Android Project, I created the Renderer for camera custom view like this.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MementoApp.Views.CameraPreview), typeof(MementoApp.Droid.CameraPreviewRenderer))]
namespace MementoApp.Droid
{
    public class CameraPreviewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MementoApp.Views.CameraPreview, MementoApp.Droid.CameraPreview>
    {
        CameraPreview cameraPreview;

        public CameraPreview CameraPreview { get { return this.cameraPreview; } }

        public CameraPreviewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MementoApp.Views.CameraPreview> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(Context);
                SetNativeControl(cameraPreview);
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe
                cameraPreview.Click -= OnCameraPreviewClicked;
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.Camera);

                // Subscribe
                cameraPreview.Click += OnCameraPreviewClicked;
            }
        }

        void OnCameraPreviewClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cameraPreview.IsPreviewing)
            {
                cameraPreview.Preview.StopPreview();
                cameraPreview.IsPreviewing = false;
            }
            else
            {
                cameraPreview.Preview.StartPreview();
                cameraPreview.IsPreviewing = true;
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Control.Preview.Release();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the CameraPreview class in the Android Project.

```
public sealed class CameraPreview : ViewGroup, ISurfaceHolderCallback
    {
        SurfaceView surfaceView;
        ISurfaceHolder holder;
        Camera.Size previewSize;
        IList<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes;
        Camera camera;
        IWindowManager windowManager;

        public bool IsPreviewing { get; set; }

        public Camera Preview
        {
            get { return camera; }
            set
            {
                camera = value;
                if (camera != null)
                {
                    supportedPreviewSizes = Preview.GetParameters().SupportedPreviewSizes;
                    RequestLayout();
                }
            }
        }

        public CameraPreview(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {
            surfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
            AddView(surfaceView);

            windowManager = Context.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();

            IsPreviewing = false;
            holder = surfaceView.Holder;
            holder.AddCallback(this);
        }

        protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            int width = ResolveSize(SuggestedMinimumWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = ResolveSize(SuggestedMinimumHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
            SetMeasuredDimension(width, height);

            if (supportedPreviewSizes != null)
            {
                previewSize = GetOptimalPreviewSize(supportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            var msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(r - l, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
            var msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(b - t, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);

            surfaceView.Measure(msw, msh);
            surfaceView.Layout(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
        }

        public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Preview != null)
                {
                    Preview.SetPreviewDisplay(holder);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"           ERROR: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            if (Preview != null)
            {
                Preview.StopPreview();
            }
        }

        public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, Android.Graphics.Format format, int width, int height)
        {
            var parameters = Preview.GetParameters();
            parameters.SetPreviewSize(previewSize.Width, previewSize.Height);
            RequestLayout();

            switch (windowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation)
            {
                case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0:
                    camera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
                    break;
                case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90:
                    camera.SetDisplayOrientation(0);
                    break;
                case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270:
                    camera.SetDisplayOrientation(180);
                    break;
            }

            Preview.SetParameters(parameters);
            Preview.StartPreview();
            IsPreviewing = true;
        }

        Camera.Size GetOptimalPreviewSize(IList<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h)
        {
            const double AspectTolerance = 0.1;
            double targetRatio = (double)w / h;

            if (sizes == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
            double minDiff = double.MaxValue;

            int targetHeight = h;
            foreach (Camera.Size size in sizes)
            {
                double ratio = (double)size.Width / size.Height;

                if (Math.Abs(ratio - targetRatio) > AspectTolerance)
                    continue;
                if (Math.Abs(size.Height - targetHeight) < minDiff)
                {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.Abs(size.Height - targetHeight);
                }
            }

            if (optimalSize == null)
            {
                minDiff = double.MaxValue;
                foreach (Camera.Size size in sizes)
                {
                    if (Math.Abs(size.Height - targetHeight) < minDiff)
                    {
                        optimalSize = size;
                        minDiff = Math.Abs(size.Height - targetHeight);
                    }
                }
            }

            return optimalSize;
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to do now is I want to retrieve some data from the CameraPreviewRenderer from the SharedProject when the "Capture" button is clicked. I created the event for capture button like this in the CameraPage.xaml.cs in the shared project like this.

```
void ButtonCapturePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Inside that event, I want to retrieve the data from the CameraPreviewRenderer in the Android project. For example, I created a property in the CameraPreviewRenderer class like this.

```
public string Data { get { return "Message from  the Android Project"; } }
```

Inside the event like, maybe I would retrieve that property like this.

```
Camera.Data //Data would be "Message from the Android Project" and Camera is the custom view.
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is correct to say that in your renderer, that `CameraPreview cameraPreview;` variable is not a `MementoApp.Views.CameraPreview` instance? You have 2 classes called `CameraPreview`?

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms Messaging Center is one way to do it. Just subscribe to the event in your Custom Renderer class.

Another way would be to create the `Data` property in your CameraPreview class instead of the CameraPreviewRenderer, and then you can set that property when you click the button. IE,

```
void ButtonCapturePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Camera.Data = ...;
}
```

Now, you'll be able to get the `Data` in the `OnElementPropertyChanged` method in your CameraPreviewRenderer class.

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == CameraPreview.DataProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        ... do what you need to do ...
    }
}
```

UPDATE: The best way to do it would be to use an event handler. In your `CameraPreview` class, create an event handler and method to invoke it:

```
public event eventHandler<MyDataObject> OnData;

public void InvokeOnData(MyDataObject obj)
{
    OnData?.Invoke(this, obj);
}
```

Then in your `CameraPreviewRenderer`'s `OnElementChanged` method, you can set up the event handler:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(...)
{
    var cameraPreview = (CameraPreview)this.Element;
    cameraPreview.OnData += HandleData;
}

private void HandleData(object sender, MyCameraObject e)
{
    ... do what you need to do ...
}
```

And then, you can invoke it this way:

```
void ButtonCapturePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Camera.InvokeOnData(your data);
}
```

Comment: Despite I'm sure the messaging center could do the trick, I'm not plenty of hope it'll give a clean, reusable and uncoupled solution to his `CameraView`... =/

Comment: Yeah, I personally don't use Messaging Center at all in my app

Comment: Neither I do. I do the best I can to avoid it.

Comment: Add the Data property in the CameraPreview class by you mean CameraPreview class in the shared project. Is it?

Comment: Yes, similar to how you already have the `Camera` BindableProperty set up. That way when the property value changes, you can listen to it in your custom renderer's OnElementPropertyChanged method

Comment: I added a better way of doing it, using an event handler

Comment: I guess his intent is to get the data from the shared project, not to send data to the android project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) in the `ButtonCapturePhoto_Clicked` method, below is my demo:

In SharedProject, define interface `IGetData`:

```
namespace MementoApp
{
    public interface IGetData
    {
        string getData();
    }
}
```

In Android project, implement the interface:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(GetDataImpl))]
namespace MementoApp.Droid
{
    public class GetDataImpl :IGetData
    {
        public string getData()
        {
            //in this method, you can also use other approaches to get the data, like delegate/event/interface.
            CameraPreviewRenderer cpr= new CameraPreviewRenderer(Application.Context);
            cpr.initData();
            return cpr.Data;
        }
    }
}
```

Your `CameraPreviewRenderer` add these( I use a method-`initData` to simulate the `Data`'s generation):

```
public string Data;
public void initData() {
    Data= "Message from  the Android Project";
}
```

And at the last, call it in the `ButtonCapturePhoto_Clicked`:

```
private void ButtonCapturePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string data = DependencyService.Get<IGetData>().getData();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("data====="+data);
}
```